# Mikrotik: Forward local ip to another local ip on specific port

Tags: nat, local-area-network, mikrotik

I'm running a Docker container on a machine on port 8090. Let's say the IP address of that machine is `192.168.0.3`. I want to forward `192.168.0.4:80` to `192.168.0.3:8090`. The machine is and may only be reachable from within the local network.

What I've tried:

```
/ip firewall nat export
add action=dst-nat chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.4 dst-port=80 \
    src-address=192.168.0.0/24 to-address=192.168.0.3 to-port=8090 \
    protocol=tcp
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.0.4 dst-port=80 \
    src-address=192.168.0.0/24 protocol=tcp
```

This doesn't work.

Am I forgetting something? I've got the feeling I'm overlooking something simple but haven't been able to figure out what.

#### Edit:

The ip address `192.168.0.4` does not resolve to anything in my network. I just want to "assign" and forward it to `192.168.0.3:8090`. The reason for this is that I want to setup a local domain name that resolves to the Docker container without having to specify a port.

Comment: is `192.168.0.4` pingable? if so, does the firewall know about this ip address on one of its interfaces? if so, is the ARP entry for `192.168.0.4` the MAC address of your firewall or is it per chance flapping? try last question on a system in the same subnet with `arping -I eth0 192.168.0.4` (replace eth0 with the correct interface name if necessary)

Comment: apart from that: using port forwarding on `192.168.0.3` looks way easier and more transparent to me.

Comment: The address is not pingable. Running the `arping` command will surely result in a timeout as well. I will update my question with some additional information.

Comment: Traffic on the same layer-3 network is delivered directly by layer-2, not layer-3, so you can't NAT (redirect) at layer-3. ARP will try to find the layer-2 address for the layer-3 address, and the resulting frames are delivered by layer-2. If ARP can't resolve the addressing, then the packet gets dropped because no frame can be built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computers in the local network try to reach IP addresses within their own subnet directly. Therefore a computer ("Workstation") with the IP address `192.168.0.105` will ignore the default gateway when trying to reach `192.168.0.4` and tries to send tcp packages directly.

This will fail if no other computer is answering Workstations call ("arp request") for the MAC address belonging to `192.168.0.4` - and none will answer, as this IP address is not in use within your local network.

You do have various choices on how to solve it:

1. add `192.168.0.4` to an interface on your firewall and use your firewall to re-route those packages
2. add `192.168.0.4` to an interface on your docker-host and redirect traffic on the docker-host itself
3. add the redirection of traffic on the docker-host and use `192.168.0.3` directly instead of `192.168.0.4`

other options may exist.

Comment: I would go with option 3, but thats my personal opinion on keeping things simple.